Residual finiteness and a gluing problem
The below flowchart is from Thurston's paper Hyperbolic structures on 3-manifolds I. I don't know if I interpreted it correctly but at the bottom it says that

Residual finiteness "implies" the solution of the general gluing problem for geometrically finite groups.

But in the series of papers on Hyperbolic structures on 3-manifolds, I couldn't find where he explained something related to the above, even what it means by "the general gluing problem". I think the arrow does not genuinely mean implying something but means they're more or less related. I can guess the "gluing problem" here is finding a fixed point of $\tau\circ\sigma$ where $\tau$ is an orientation reversing fixed-point-free involution $\mathrm{Teich}(\overline{\partial M})\to \mathrm{Teich}(\partial M)$ and $\sigma$ is a Skinning map $\mathrm{Teich}(\partial M)\to\mathrm{Teich}(\overline{\partial M})$ for quasi-Fuchsian end $\partial M$ of a complete hyperbolic 3-manifold $M$ with conformal boundary. I know this gluing problem is concerned during Thurston's proof of hyperbolization of Haken manifold. But the main question I want to know is the relationship with the residual finiteness.

Q. What is the meaning of "general gluing problem" here and how the residual finiteness is related to the gluing problem?



Thurston probably has in mind the orbifold trick. It is explained in the book by Kapovich "Hyperbolic manifolds and discrete groups" and the  paper by Otal "Thurston's hyperbolization of Haken manifolds."

This does not address your question regarding the "Residual Finiteness" box... however, as one might discern by examining several arrows in this diagram, an arrow from A to B does not necessarily mean "A implies B". A better interpretation might be "an understanding of A leads to an understanding of B".

Thurston never finished his project, hence, we cannot know for sure what exactly did he have in mind in this part of the diagram. Here is what we know:

Fundamental groups of good compact 3-dimensional orbifolds are residually finite. This was proven for "geometrizable" (i.e. admitting a decomposition in geometric pieces) 3-dimensional orbifolds by Hempel in

Hempel, John, Residual finiteness for 3-manifolds, Combinatorial group theory and topology, Sel. Pap. Conf., Alta/Utah 1984, Ann. Math. Stud. 111, 379-396 (1987). ZBL0772.57002.
Hempel credits Thurston with the idea. However, as far as I know, this result is not used in any of the proofs of Thurston's theorem.

The available detailed proofs of Thurston's theorem given in

Kapovich, Michael, Hyperbolic manifolds and discrete groups, Progress in Mathematics (Boston, Mass.). 183. Boston, MA: Birkhäuser. xxv, 467 p. (2001). ZBL0958.57001.
Otal, Jean-Pierre, Thurston’s hyperbolization of Haken manifolds, Hsiung, C. C. (ed.) et al., Surveys in differential geometry. Vol. III. A supplement to the Journal of Differential Geometry. Lectures on geometry and topology in honor of the 80th birthday of Chuan-Chih Hsiung, Harvard University, Cambridge, MA, USA, May 3-5, 1996. Boston, MA: International Press. 77-194 (1998). ZBL0997.57001.
Otal, Jean-Pierre, The hyperbolization theorem for fibered 3-manifolds. Transl. from the French by Leslie D. Kay, SMF/AMS Texts and Monographs. 7. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). xiv, 126 p. (2001). ZBL0986.57001.
as well as an outline in
Morgan, J. W., On Thurston’s uniformization theorem for three-dimensional manifolds (chapter V), The Smith conjecture, Pure Appl. Math. 112, 37-126 (1984). ZBL0599.57002.
all use Thurston's "orbifold trick." The proofs require a construction of finite manifold covers of some 3-dimensional orbifolds. But the proofs are direct and do not use the more general residual finiteness results (neither the one in Hempel's paper, nor Maltsev's 1940 theorem for finitely generated matrix groups).
Of course, Thurston's theorem is also a consequence of Perelman's, but that's not relevant for the purpose of your question.
